# Arrays-C programming

Tags: c, arrays

Hey guys please help me out here.I intend to get the array "ABD" as output.  I have entered the array "AAABD" as input and I am trying to accomplish this through comparing two successive elements and deleting one of them if found equal.

What is wrong with my code??

```c++
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
    char ar[5]={'A','A','A','B','D'};
    int a;
    a=5;
    int i;
    int j;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {

        for(i=0;i<a;i++)
        {
            if(ar[i]==ar[i+1])
            {
                for(j=i;j<a-1;j++)
                {
                    ar[j]=ar[j+1];
                }
                a=a-1;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d",a);
    for(i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
        printf("%c",ar[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? How does the actual behaviour differ from the expected behaviour? Is there an error message?

Answer (score 1):

The index `i` is used twice in different for-loops in your code. Bad copy paste ?

```
[...]
  for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{

for(i=0;i<a;i++)
{
[...]
```

Then you copy the 2nd élement in the fisrt one, and the loop for go on. The copied second élément will not be check with the 3rd element value.

lets gets an example :

here is the input table AAABD with index : {{A0},{A1},{A2},{B3},{D4}}

for iteration i=0:

test is `A0 = A1`   => the table becomes {{A1},{A2},{B3},{D4}}

for iteration i=1:

test is `A2 != B3`   => the table is not changed. You have to redone the test on i=0 once.

## EDIT

This recursive function shall do it. As it is recursive, it could be greedy.
(( I have nothing to test it right now but I think the code is ok ))

```
// for null terminated string
void my_function (char*table)
{ 
  int i;
  int j;
  for(i=0;i<strlen(table)-1;i++)
  {
      if(table[i]==table[i+1])
      {
        my_function(table + i + 1);
        for(j=i;j<strlen(table);j++)
        {
            table[j]=table[j+1];
        }
      }
  }
}
```

## EDIT 2 : to reply to sp2danny comment

```
// for non null terminated string
void my_function (char*table,int *size)
{ 
  int i;
  int j;
  for(i=0;i<*size-1;i++)
  {
      if(table[i]==table[i+1])
      {
        *size -= i+1;
        my_function(table + i + 1,size);
        for(j=i;j<*size;j++)
        {
            table[j]=table[j+1];
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: the array wasn't null-terminated, and how does the caller know how much shorter the array got?

Comment: @sp2danny, the user know the array length with strlen in the case of a NULL terminated string, with size value in the case of a non terminated string.

Answer (score 0):

1) you have one loop to many 
2) you increase `i` even if you decrease `a`

```
int main()
{
    char ar[]={'A','A','A','B','D'};
    int i=0,j,a=sizeof(ar);
    while(i<a-1)
    {
        if(ar[i]==ar[i+1])
        {
            for(j=i;j<a-1;j++)
                ar[j]=ar[j+1];
            --a;
        } else
            ++i;
    }
    printf("%d\n",a);
    for(i=0;i<a;i++) printf("%c ",ar[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: thanks!..btw what is wrong with this loop??                        for(i=0;i<a;)
    {
        if(ar[i]==ar[i+1])
        {
            for(j=i;j<a-1;j++)
                ar[j]=ar[j+1];
            --a;
        } else
            ++i;
    }

Comment: for one, the condition should be `i<a-1` not `i<a` because you test `ar[i+1]`

Comment: and since the part that usually holds `++i` is empty, I thought `while` fitted better. mostly taste though.